# SELECT ALL YAML

Tags: select, yaml

This could be a dumb question. I've never worked with YAML before but I'm now coming across it in a project of mine. Is there a way to "Select all" in YAML? Or do something similar.

To give you some context, I'm using this tool called the HOT Export Tool. (https://export.hotosm.org/en/v3/) It allows you to export OSM data. I would like to download all of hte data in a selected area but they dont have that option. Instead one of the options is to use YAML to select the features. Example code:

```
plenet_osm_points:
    types:
      -points
    select:
      - 'access:roof'
      -'addr:housenumber'
    where:
      -building is NOT NULL
```

That is just a small snippet but hopefully the question makes more sense.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what you mean with "select all" here. please post an example YAML and the desired output.

Comment: YAML is comparable to JSON. It is not a programming language, and also not a database query language. It is a data serialization language. But one can use it as a language to *create* queries. How this works depends on the software/tool. Use the documentation they provide.

Comment: Aw. That makes a lot more sense. Thanks for the fast reply.